# HttpURLConnection, OAuth 2.0 on Android app

Tags: java, android, api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have intended to do an Android app which access to a public `API`, `trakt.tv` to be more specific. [Reading the API](http://docs.trakt.apiary.io/#reference/authentication-oauth/authorize-application), the first step is `Authentication` using `OAuth`, but I am bit lost with it.

I read lot of `how-to` tutorials which explains advanced `HttpURLConnection` and `OAuth` methods but I think I need a starter guide or something similar, so I am looking for any tip, any article you recommend to start with.

Basically I cannot understand exactly how `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` or `DELETE` works, and how can I apply it to a `OAuth 2.0` login form.

Comment: Have you tried to use this library: https://github.com/UweTrottmann/trakt-java ?

Comment: I didn't do it (didn't see it). Seems very interesting so I will check it. Thanks :]